# Управление выводом дробной части double в Java

Tags: java, double, деление

Как вывести дробную часть double в Java?
Что бы число d было равно 178.90 а не 178.9

```
int num = 17890;
double d = (double)num/100;
System.out.println(d); *//выводит 178.9, а не 178.90*
```

Comment: java? Посмотри printf()

Comment: `num % 100` - дробная часть, только дополнение нулём спереди прийдётся всёравно в форматировании указывать.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте DecimalFormat

```
int num = 17890;
double d = (double)num/100;
System.out.println(d); //выводит 178.9, а не 178.90
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
System.out.println(format.format(d)); // выводит 178.90
```

Answer (score 2):

Для печати с точностью до 10 знаков, после запятой надо использовать такой код:

```
double d=1.23456789;
System.out.printf("d=%.10f\n", d);
```

[документация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)